# Python - How to normalize audio in a video file?

Tags: python, audio, video

By "normalize," I mean "increase/decrease the overall volume so that the maximum reaches maximum headroom."

I'm part of my school's news crew and teachers send commercials in, but they are often too loud or too soft. I'd like to create a program the normalizes the audio (no compression or limiting). It would generally have to work with .mov and .wmv files. Can anyone guide me toward some good tutorials, libraries, etc.?

Comment: ["It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form."](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)

Comment: Bobince answered it perfectly.

Comment: Just because someone answered it doesn't make it a good question, this was way too vague and broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demultiplexing the audio stream out of the AV container and decompressing it: you'll want a wrapper for the ffmpeg library. eg try pyffmpeg, AVbin, pymedia.

Normalizing: use a Numpy array of per-sample integers, find the max then multiply the array to amplify/attenuate volume. Consider using ReplayGain.

Recompressing the audio and remultiplexing with the original video stream into a new container: same libraries as above, but more likely to cause difficulties, especially for proprietary containers and codecs. (eg I believe ffmpeg can only produce a really old WMA version.)

It's not going to be straightforward and I'm not sure it will necessarily be worth it, in comparison with using a readymade app. For example ffmpeg itself has a command line you could batch script, and eg avidemux has both command line and GUI interfaces.

Also, I suspect you'll find simple peak normalisation won't get you very far in terms of making effective volume levels similar; usually you'll need to use some quantity of dynamic range compression too.

Comment: Thanks. I'm a novice, so from what you're telling me, this is way over my head. I'm a musician, so I understand that they wouldn't be quite the same loudness simply with normalization - I mentioned in the question that I didn't want to use compression or limiting. I can easily do this with Ableton Live but it would be better if I could write a small program for school use.

Comment: Heh... yeah, it's not a good place to be starting with any programming language really: video is hard, especially in the real world where you have weird formats or stream corruption to cope with. I'm not sure what Ableton's capabilities with video are, but what you would generally want to do would be to process the audio stream whilst retain the original video, without having to decompress and recompress it (resulting in quality loss). That's something tools like avidemux in copy-mode can do.

Comment: (Then again if you are importing into a wider project, maybe you do want to transcode the video to a different format standardised across your sources...)

Comment: I downloaded avidemux. I think it will work if I just write a script for it. Thanks!